# WhizzyTeX custom folder for files

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to have Emacs' WhizzyTex preview mode store the files in a designated folder rather than the current folder (we're talking 6 files per previewed document)? I feel like LaTeX, BibTeX and Flymake already produce enough files (a grand total of 16 files for 1 paper)

Comment: I don't use WhizzyTex, I cannot help you, but which files does Flymake produce?

Comment: [file]_flymake.aux and .log

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating another folder, you can have a `clear-whizzy-preview` function:

```
(defun clear-whizzy-preview () (shell-command "rm -f *flymake*"))
```

You can change the `*flymake*` part to delete other file(s) too (for example all `.log` file)